# Ctrl+Alt+Print does not copy to clipboard on Ubuntu 19.10 GNOME 3.34.1

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>, the clipboard is unaffected. I can verify this by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> and can paste it into https://imgur.com/ just fine (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> does copy to the clipboard, but it requires selecting a region), but if I subsequently use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> and paste into imgur, it pastes what was in the clipboard already, indicating that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> is not updating the clipboard at all.

In keyboard shortcuts, for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> shows this:

[image]

That specifically says:

> Copy a screenshot of a window to clipboard

Which means to me that it should update the clipboard with the screenshot of the entire window.

It does not.

Is this a bug or is there something that is misconfigured that would cause it to behave in this manner?

Comment: Works for me, so could be related to your specific keyboard or keyboard layout. Try assigning another shortcut combination: does it work then?

Comment: Well, I think you are on to something. I am using a special keyboard. when I assign "Copy a screenshot of a window to clipboard" to CTRL+ALT+=, it works, but when I assign it back to the default, it stops working.  I don't believe I have a special keyboard layout.

Comment: That will be your workaround, unless you succeed to investigate your keyboard and/or keyboard driver at a deeper level.

Comment: I do a screen capture/shot, get the quick flash indication + sound but the image isn't being added to the clipboard.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: "screen capture/shot" using what sequence of keys?

Comment: All keyboard sequences. Only the screenshot from the ui app works.

Comment: I assigned to Ctrl + Print + = and it works. When I go to reassign, I press Ctrl + Alt + Print but the shortcut tool only recognizes Alt + Print. It's like Ctrl is being captured by some other process. Any thoughts @vanadium ?